# The dot product of a vector with its transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I just wanted to check my proof here, because I am wrestling with a wider problem that contains within it this issue.

I have a vector, V which is of length N, so to describe the shape of the vector would be (N,1). If I multiply this vector with its transpose, say V', would it not depend upon which way I multiplied them?

I.e. vector V is of shape (N,1), and V' is of shape (1,N). If I compute VV', then the resulting output is (N,N), but if I compute V'V, the output is (1,1).

Is my reasoning correct, or am I missing something?

Comment: @DavidH It depends on what you mean by the "dot-product". In the computer science community, the dot product refers to standard matrix multiplication, and your statement is correct. In the mathematical community, the "dot-product" of two vectors is always a scalar.

Comment: @DavidH I think it would be helpful if you explained a bit more about the wider problem

Comment: @BenGrossmann, I am working with equations from a paper in the computer science community, so I would assume that we are talking about that. The wider problem would take too long to type out, so here's a summary. I am working with a code that computes the explained variance of a model gamma against the original data V. I am trying to check whether or not the computation used in the code is correct against what the actual equation is. It appears that what Morgan called the "dot product" is computed in this computation. But for some reason, a normalised standard deviation is used instead of it.

Comment: @DavidH Does the paper mention anything about shifting/normalizing the values of $V$ so that the mean of its entries is zero? For a mean-zero vector $V$, $\frac{V'\cdot V}N$ (where $N$ is the number of entries) is the variance of the entries.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Apologies in advance but we can't get to the bottom of this without explaining everything it seems. Here's part one: in the script there is a normalisation so that each entry has a mean of zero. The explained variance computation is essentially this variance equation that you cite, but is then plugged into another equation.: The variance of the model is $$_^2= ∑_(=1)^(_)〖(_^′ _−(Γ_κ^′ _ )^2)/(_ (_−1))〗$$. Each $V_t$ is of length $N_s$, and $N_T$ is the number of  $V_t$'s that we have. $Γ_κ$ is the model, which is a vector of length $_$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann the variance of the data is computed with $$_^2= ∑_(=1)^(_)〖(_^′ _)/(_ (_−1))$$ These two equations are then applied to $R^2$: $$^2=1 −  (_^2)/(_^2 )$$. Plugging in these variances, and reducing down, you get: $$^2= (∑_(=1)^(_)〖(Γ_κ^′ _ )^2  〗)/(∑_(=1)^(_)〖(_^′ _) 〗)$$. But when I look at the computation in the script, the denominator is inputted as the standard deviation, rather than the dot product of $V$ with its transpose. That's the whole issue. (sorry about the formatting, I'm new here)

Comment: Correction: Gamma is of length $N_s$, not $N_T$

Comment: @DavidH Interesting, I'm not sure what's going on there. You might want to either add all that to your post or make a new post explaining all that. If you have a link to the paper (assuming it can be freely accessed), that would be useful too

Comment: I've figured it out. Essentially they have incorrectly applied standard deviation instead of variance. I can still send the paper if you're still interested, but regardless, let me know how it is I accept your comments as answer, and I'll put it up as answered.